# Why is this plotting as 2 separate plots? Adding geom_encircle breaks it out into a separate plot, but I want them on the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why is this plotting as 2 separate plots? Adding geom_encircle breaks it out into a separate plot, but I want them on the same plot: [image: 2 plots image]

I'm plotting a dataframe with the ggcyto wrapper for ggplot, and I want to circle the datapoints of a subset of this dataframe which I have split off into a different dataframe. But it keeps plotting two different plots: one with the scatterplot/density plot, and one with the circle. ggplot should be able to plot two different dataframes in the same plot right, so what gives?

```
ggcyto(data = fcsSet[[1]],
aes(x = 55, y = 59)) +
geom_hex(bins=300) +
stat_density_2d(colour = "black",bins=100,size=.2)+
xlim(-.1,4) +
ylim(-.1,4) +
scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10", limits = c(NA,4)) +
scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10", limits = c(NA,4)) +
geom_encircle(data = splitff[[4]])
```

Comment: From the ggcyto documentation: "ggCyto automatically facets by the name variable, which usually represents individual FCS files.". Do you maybe have a `name` variable that's different in the split data?

Comment: Thanks @iod, because it’s the default behavior, I had to add this line: facet_grid(rows = 1,cols = NULL)
Now I get a single plot, thanks!